# What is the lifetime of `&mut rand::thread_rng()` passed into a random sample function?

Tags: memory, memory-management, scope, reference, rust

`K` is an `i64` and `points` is a `Vec<Vec<i64>>` that is used to represent points in an n-dim space.

```
let mut centroids: Vec<Vec<i64>> = 
    rand::seq::sample_iter(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 
                           points.iter(), 
                           K as usize).unwrap();
```

Is `rand::thread_rng()` moved into the function scope and thus gotten rid of at the end of the function? (making the whole thing not leak memory)

If not, is there a way to do so without declaring it separately? What led me to this question is the way the `drop` function works since it pretty much employs the same idea.

Comment: Additionally, you will get *far* better answers if you provide a [MCVE]. For example, instead of using prose to tell us what `K` and `points` are, show the code for them. You can even write a function that accepts `points` so you don't have to actually define it.

Comment: Consider sticking to one question per post, as they do not seem to be sufficiently related. I would also advise you to read the respective documentation for [`rand::thread_rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/fn.thread_rng.html), which should just about answer the first question.

Comment: No, the value of `rand::thread_rng()` is not moved into the function, although the mutable reference to the value is. The RNG value itself is destroyed at the end of the statement.

Comment: @Shepmaster The output of `thread_rng()` is, in turn, a reference-counted pointer to a thread-local value. The inner RNG value is not destroyed, but the Rc is. :)